# How to access a customized profile with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, chrome-profile

I am trying to access a gmail account in a customized chrome profile, everything is working, but it seems that I can't load the account:

```
options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={expanduser}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 5")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

To make sure that it does access the right profile, I ran the code and went to `chrome://version` and it gave me the right path, so is there something wrong with the code ?

I don't know if this can help or not, I just found that when I access the profile manually, the profile path end with the profile name, but when the app opens it, it loads the default inside that profile.

**Edit:**

Tried to delete that Default Folder, but when the app runs, it recreates it, I think this can be a start point

Comment: why I am feeling so alone :)

Comment: Why did you deleted your answer? It it resolves this issue this can be useful for other people too! Also, I wanted to upvote it...

Comment: I found that it opens the default user data then switches to the profile, what I aim for is to open a different window

Comment: I want to open multiple windows with different profiles, and this doesn't achieve it, though I undeleted it

Comment: if you have any ideas, you can share

Comment: I would be happy to, but I have no...

Comment: I will open another question for this specific issue

Comment: seems like I have to wait some time to post another question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I need to give the User Data Path, then add another argument to the options called `profile-directory` and give it the profile name, the final code like this :

```
options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={expanduser}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument(f"profile-directory={profile}")
```

Comment: just a note for other people, this does opens a customized profile, but if you want to open multiple windows with different profiles, this won't help